# Yii2.0 advanced template user-management Module

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, user-management

I am working with Yii2 with advanced template with frontend and backend.

i just want to implement Yii2.0 `user-management` Module in `backend` section. will it be possible?

in `yii2 basic` i have tried below reference and its working fine.

`Ref : https://github.com/webvimark/user-management`

But when i am trying same thing in `advanced template` i am stuck while migration thing.

one things is about migration code step 2 in above reference url i don't know where i need to put this code

```
<?php
'modules'=>[
    'user-management' => [
        'class' => 'webvimark\modules\UserManagement\UserManagementModule',
            'controllerNamespace'=>'vendor\webvimark\modules\UserManagement\controllers', // To prevent yii help from crashing
    ],
], ?>
```

because in my folder structure which i downloaded from site for advanced i have not found `config/console.php` file in `backend` and also not found from `common` folder.

when i am running commands below its gives me error.

`./yii migrate --migrationPath=vendor/webvimark/module-user-management/migrations/`

Will appreciate with any help!

Answer (score 0):

You just try this Yii2.0 Advanced

1. in your cofig/main.php

> 'user' => [
>           'class' => 'webvimark\modules\UserManagement\components\UserConfig',
>
> ```
>     // Comment this if you don't want to record user logins
>
>     'on afterLogin' => function($event) {
>             \webvimark\modules\UserManagement\models\UserVisitLog::newVisitor($event->identity->id);
>
>         }
> ],        'view' => [
>
>      'theme' => [
>
>          'pathMap' => [
>
>             //'@app/views' => '@vendor/dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset/example-views/yiisoft/yii2-app'
>
>           '@app/views' => '@backend/views/layouts'
>
>          ],
>      ],
> ], ?>
> ```

its working for me